# Job trigger on 40th day after quarter starts

Tags: autosys

The autosys job should trigger on the **40th day from the start of every quarter**.

Scenario:
1 Jan 2021 + 40 days (inclusive start date) is on 9 Feb 2021

likewise, 10May2021 9Aug2021 9Nov2021

In case of the 40th day to be a non-working day (Sat and Sun), the job should be scheduled for the next business day.

Comment: Use Cycle and Exdende calander. Refer some of my previous answer and you would find one such case.

Comment: Don't ask me :D I know nothing about autosyc ^^

Comment: @Piyush can you  let me know :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an extended calendar as:

```
extended_calendar: QUARTER_START_40_PLUS
workday: mo,tu,we,th,fr
non_workday: W
holiday: W
holcal:
cyccal: 
adjust: 39
condition: jan#1|apr#1|jul#1|oct#1
description: Runs on 40th day after start of quarter, incase its a sat or sun job runs on next mon
```

Next Run Dates:

```
09Aug2021
09Nov2021
09Feb2022
10May2022
```

Comment: Thanks @Piyush except Feb run dates others are showing correct Run date
For Feb month it is showing 11Feb2022 instead of 09Feb2022  not sure why so

Comment: yup, its strange at first look, jan1 jan2 being sat and sun, causing the +2 day effect. it work if i turn off the sat sun condition

Comment: i dont see a way to sort this out further, there is a trade off in each way. Good luck